# Laravel: Method [allowMultiUser] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am totally newbie in Laravel - I am using since today.

I am using CRUDBooster to create form under my requirements, one of fields which I need is file field. So I add new field in module manager, type=filemanager. New field displays in form, but when I try choose files, I got error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 82:
Method [allowMultiUser] does not exist.
```

Laravel: 5.3.2

Server: XAMPP/Apache2

Comment: You need to post more codes to help. Share the form along with the route and controller which the form posts to.

Comment: As I said I created that form by wizard in CRUDBooster. So what should I share, screenshot? In `Step 3 - Form display` I selected type `filemanager` and save wizard. Then I have new module in left menu, with complete CRUD.

Comment: Please Share your controller code

Comment: https://pastebin.com/VGp3Jrgr